# Scaffold.geometryOf() must only be accessed during the paint phase

Tags: flutter, floating-action-button, flutter-windows

Exception is thrown when debugging on windows, stacktrace:

```
ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Scaffold.geometryOf() must only be accessed during the paint phase.
The ScaffoldGeometry is only available during the paint phase, because its value is computed during the animation and layout phases prior to painting.
#0      _ScaffoldGeometryNotifier.value.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:835:9)
#1      _ScaffoldGeometryNotifier.value (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:842:6)
#2      _BottomAppBarClipper.getClip (package:flutter/src/material/bottom_app_bar.dart:238:35)
```

The stacktrace is hinting at getting geometry values from a BottomAppBar which is what I have in my widget. This error is followed by a lot of error messages for mouse_tracker when I move the mouse on the screen:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/mouse_tracker.dart': Failed assertion: line 195 pos 12: '!_debugDuringDeviceUpdate': is not true.
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
#2      MouseTracker._deviceUpdatePhase (package:flutter/src/rendering/mouse_tracker.dart:195:12)
```

Nothing on the screen is clickable after this.

The error occurs only after the FloatingActionButton is pressed, and not if the back button on the page is pressed. The onPressed for the FAB is:

```
  void onOkPressed() {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FAB is contained in the bottom app bar, try setting the FAB location to float

from

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: const AppBar(),
    bottomNavigationBar: const BottomAppBar(),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: onOkPressed,
      child: const Icon(Icons.check, size: 32),
    ),
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endContained,
....
```

to

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: const AppBar(),
    bottomNavigationBar: const BottomAppBar(),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: onOkPressed,
      child: const Icon(Icons.check, size: 32),
    ),
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
....
```

Comment: What if my design calls for a floating action button that is contained within the bottom app bar? Is this not an option?

Comment: This bug only occurred in debug mode and on windows. Release mode on windows is fine. As stated elsewhere, link to official bug is here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/140733. Had no idea they would link to my old post as a suggested solution, this was just meant to be a hacky workaround when debugging on windows

Answer (score 1):

I encountered exactly the same problem. Setting the maintainState to true when pushing the second page in the Navigator, seems to solve the problem.

```
Navigator.push(
       context,
       MaterialPageRoute(
          maintainState: true, // <------ change this
          builder: (context) => SecondPageWithFAB()
          )
       );
```

Then in the SecondPageWithFAB you can call the Navigator.pop as before:

```
void onOkPressed() {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is still open. [Here.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/140733)
You can use `flutter build` instead.
Or `flutter run --release`